# Runtime error when importing basemap into spyder

Tags: python, runtime-error, spyder, matplotlib-basemap

I installed spyder onto my computer a few months ago and it has worked fine until I needed to produce a map with station plots and topography. I simply tried to import matplotlib-basemap and get the following error:

> File "<ipython-input-12-6634632f8d36>", line 1, in 
>   runfile('C:/Users/Isa/Documents/Freedman/2018/ENVIROCOMP/Stationplots.py', wdir='C:/Users/Isa/Documents/Freedman/2018/ENVIROCOMP')
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Isa/Documents/Freedman/2018/ENVIROCOMP/Stationplots.py", line 15, in 
>       from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, shiftgrid, cm
>
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
>
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 951, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 890, in _find_spec
>
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 864, in _find_spec_legacy
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 253, in find_module
>       fp, pathname, (ext,mode,ty) = imp.find_module(fullname,package_path)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 271, in find_module
>       "not {}".format(type(path)))
>
> RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>

If anyone has gone through this or understands this type of error suggest a way to make basemap work on spyder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This error was fixed in our **3.2.8** version, released in March/2018.

Since you're using Anaconda, please open the Anaconda prompt and run there

`conda update spyder`

to get the fix.

Comment: A simple fix! Thank you!

Comment: Could you mark my answer as correct, by selecting the green check mark next to it? Thanks!